# Replacement for wine

Tags: substitutions, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a substitute for red or white wine in a recipe?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/what-is-a-substitute-for-red-or-white-wine-in-a-recipe)

I am making a short rib recipe which calls for white wine in the brazing liquid.  I don't have any wine, what would you recommend I used in place of it?  Will I be missing out on a lot not using the wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wine has three main functions, as I see it: liquid for braising, acidity, and flavor. You can get the liquid from any source. Acidity could come from vinegar, lemon, or tomato. Flavor can come from herbs, spices, or fruit. Certainly, the flavor will be different without wine, but that does not mean worse. I usually throw in whatever I have around the kitchen. For example, the last time I braised short ribs, I used beef stock, tomato paste, and 4 plums.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a sweet vinegar before in place of wine, you don't have to add much and it give's recipes a bit more kick due to the acidity.You will have to use your judgement as you definitely won't want to add as much vinegar as you would wine.

Answer (score 2):

Beef and chicken stock are commonly used as braising liquids, either on their own or combined with wine. You could just use plain water and still accomplish braising (you just need low, slow, moist heat), but you'll definitely be missing out on some flavor.