# What to use instead of white wine in recipes?

Tags: substitutions, alcohol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a substitute for red or white wine in a recipe?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/what-is-a-substitute-for-red-or-white-wine-in-a-recipe)

I am Muslim and we do not consume alcohol in any form. I love European cuisine, but many of the recipes call for the use of white wine, or red wine or alcohol in any other form.

So I was thinking that there must be something that can be used instead of wine in those recipes (e.g. Swiss Fondue).

Comment: why not just skip the wine

Comment: Closed as a duplicate (see the [FAQ] for more details). If you have a particular recipe you'd like to adapt, feel free to ask a question about that specifically (i.e. fondue without white wine).

Comment: @Prometheus87 Most fruits or high sugar vegetables and even some grains contain small amounts of alcohol. So sorry you have probably been drinking the stuff all your life!

Comment: @TFD you thin i don't know that? that stuff is unavoidable. It's the avoidable I am talking about.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the time, the major purpose of the wine is acidity. You can get this with lemon juice, tomato, or vinegar instead. Since the flavor is different, you will need to experiment by tasting, and probably use different amounts, but you should still be able to get good results. In the fondue recipe you mention, you would probably do well with a combination of lemon juice and red wine vinegar.

Answer (score 2):

Would it just be something as simple as using a non-alcohol wine? I'm not really sure if there're any that are 100% free of alcohol, but  what if you boiled a non-alcohol wine to remove even more (or possibly all) of the alcohol in it?

Comment: how can the alcohol content be tested?

Comment: i mean after the boiling

Comment: Someone did that test and found that it is very difficult to remove all alcohol: http://www.ochef.com/165.htm

Comment: Actually, there is such a thing as non-alcoholic wine. It's called unsweetened apple juice. :)

Comment: perhaps Jake is on the right track. rather than using a wine claiming to be non-alcohol, it would be easier/safer to just use an unsweetened fruit juice.

Comment: @prometheuspk - Since it seems you mention in the comments to the Q, that you're OK with some foods naturally containing a small amount of alcohol, you *might* really consider de-alcoholized wine. The numbers I saw the few times I bought one where such that its alcohol content was well in the range of fruit juices. (typically it has to have `< 1% vol` around here)