# Dry white wine substitute for slow cooker garlic chicken recipe

Tags: substitutions

What would be a good substitute for the wine? I do not know what to do with wine I have never cooked with it and I wouldn't use enough of it to make it worth buying some.

Slow Cooker Garlic Chicken

Ingredients

1/2 cup fat-free, low-sodium chicken broth (certified gluten-free if necessary)
3 tablespoons dry white wine
2 tablespoons cognac
1 (3 1/3-pound) whole chicken, skinned and cut into 8 pieces
1 1/2 teaspoons extra-virgin olive oil
1 1/2 teaspoons butter
1/4 teaspoon salt
1/8 teaspoon freshly ground black pepper
40 garlic cloves, peeled (about 4 whole heads)
2 teaspoons fresh thyme leaves
4 teaspoons chopped fresh parsley (optional)

Comment: Hunter, welcome. With questions like this, it is a wise idea to do a *quick search* - chances are good that we already *have* an answer. Try [this one](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/what-is-a-substitute-for-red-or-white-wine-in-a-recipe?rq=1).

Comment: Oops okay I looked and I couldn't find a good answer. Thanks

Comment: And quick formatting hint: *two* blanks at the end of the like force a line break.

Comment: If the linked question does *not* solve the substitution question *for your specific recipe*, we'll probably come up with more ideas. In this case: I'd just leave it out or use a dash more broth.

Comment: You can freeze leftover wine if you leave a little room for expansion in the container (and keep it upright especially for strong reds, it can get slightly slushy and escape). You can (in many countries) buy mini bottles of wine; in France they sell <200ml cartons (<1 cup) cheaply. On the front they seem marketed for picnics, but in the back there's a recipe. We bring them back by the dozen.

Comment: Instead of buying wine in a tall, dark glass wine bottle, you can also buy a small bottle of cooking wine that will keep for a very long time.  I use this (http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/6176SHdIgfL._SL1000_.jpg) brand, and have one red and one white in my cupboard.  I usually have a good wine bottle of each in the fridge for this purpose too. This is assuming you aren't opposed to alcohol in general.