# what is [flavor-wise] the closest nonalcoholic substitute for white wine and red wine?

Tags: substitutions, wine

White wine and red wine have great flavors when added to a dish. But because I'm on medication, I'm not able to use wine (my body would have odd reactions when I consume food cooked in white wine) I wonder what is flavor-wise the closest nonalcoholic substitute for white wine and red wine?

I have looked at [What is a substitute for red or white wine in a recipe?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/what-is-a-substitute-for-red-or-white-wine-in-a-recipe/1334#1334) But the answers were not satisfactory. For example, chicken stock has a completely different flavor when substituted for white wine and so does white grape juice. What is [flavor-wise] the closest nonalcoholic substitute for white wine and red wine? Thank you!

Comment: It might be a good substitute, but because of that, it might also cause the same odd reactions white wine causes. Something to discuss with the person who prescribed the medication. If it's the alcohol in white wine causing the odd reactions, use in cooking might also be safe, as the alcohol evaporates quickly in most recipes.

Comment: As a chemist I doubt that substituting white wine vinegar for white wine would yield the same taste. If you can't have alcohol then you're just going to have to accept a different taste.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I believe this to be a duplicate of the question you linked. An answer that you find unsatisfactory doesn't change that. I also agree with @remco re white wine vinegar as it is a natural fermentation of white wine. Not to mention that it is going to taste like vinegar. Your other option would be to buy a non-alcoholic or alcohol free white wine. They are pretty widely available.

Comment: @Cindy I didn't know those exist. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! Hope to see more from you! You may want to take our tour and visit our help pages to learn more about the site. Both can be found under the question mark (?) dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: @Cindy Hi Cindy, what are some examples of non-alcholic or alcohol free white wines? I just came back from the grocery store, and people there told me they don't have it (and have not heard of "non-aocholic white wine"). Thank you!

Comment: @Cindy You might consider posting an answer to the other question; I don't think there's actually one about nonalcoholic wine, and if it's an answer here and this is a duplicate, it must be an answer there!

Comment: @thefarseer See my answer to the linked question.

Comment: @Cascabel Answer posted  to the linked question and VTC.

Answer (score 3):

I depends on the recipe, but generally no, white wine vinegar is a very different product than white wine. Vinegar is produced when bacteria eat alcohol and produce acid which changes the flavor dramatically. If the recipe calls for acid already (for instance lemon juice) then it can work, you just reduce the additional acid. The result will still be different though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get de-alcoholised wine or don't want to (as it's had the alcohol removed that's still off-limits for some people) you'd be better off using a mixture of grape juice and lemon juice, possibly with water. There are various non-brewed wine-like drinks but they're less appealing than they sound.

The proportions of juices depends on what you're cooking, so I suggest you taste as you go. It won't be the same flavour, but it will be compatible and close. In some recipes you can change the flavour and use a sharp apple juice, but that will be more of a difference.