# Are substitutions for vodka allowed when making a vodka cream sauce

Tags: substitutions, sauce, vodka

If I am making a vodka cream sauce and I realize that there is no vodka (or not enough) to make the recipe, what would an acceptable substitute be?

Comment: Related: [why add a shot of vodka to a cream sauce?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18566)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of vodka in a cream sauce is to enhance the flavor by allowing spices that are not soluble in water to dissolve into the ethanol contained in the vodka. A suitable substitute would be any mild flavored strong alcohol.