# Should I boil the alcohol out of marinade?

Tags: pork, alcohol, marinade

A recipe for cooking pork calls for sake in the marinade. Should I boil the alcohol out or should I marinate with the alcohol intact? I read somewhere that alcohol can cook the meat just like acid, but what I can't figure out is whether that could be beneficial and actually improve the end result.

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/659/cooking-away-alcohol - it's not as easy as you think to boil off most of the alcohol.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the recipe specifically directs you to cook the marinade, you should just use it as is.

The only time you would normally cook a marinade is *after* it is used, in reducing it for use as a sauce—and of course, not all marinades are suitable for such use.

Comment: That's part of the problem, the recipe didn't really say to cook it or not :(

Comment: Assume not.  Its like a recipe calling for water--don't assume it is frozen or boiling unless specified explicitly.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But academically for my learning purpose, would the alcohol "cook" the meat?

Comment: It may denature the protein at the surface, but is unlikely to penetrate very deep; if you are subsequently cooking the item anyway (since you said the recipe is pork, I assume you are), I wouldn't worry about it overmuch.  Whatever effect it may have is anticipated in your recipe.  Countless traditions from French to Chinese marinate meats in alcohol containing marinades.

Comment: Not to mention, the alcohol content in these marinades is typically so weak to begin with, if it ever *does* denature anything, it would take days.