# Create hot "sauce" from capsaicin extract

Tags: chemistry, spicy-hot, hot-sauce

There are a lot of hot sauces like "Blairs Mega Death" with more than 500.000 scoville heat units. However, they do have some odd taste, which I don't really like.

So I'm thinking of creating a sauce from capsaicin or nonivamide extract. These are pure chemicals with 16.000.000 and 9.200.000 SHU respectively and would be perfect candidates for creating tasteless but very hot sauces. I already have nonivamide at home. Capsaicin is something I could get easily over the internet.

Since you really can't just put them on your food, you have to dissolve or mix it with either a liquid or another powder. I don't think I can use a powder because that would never create a homogeneous mixture. So I'm thinking of a liquid.

**Facts:**

**Capsaicin** is soluble in alcohol, ether, benzene, slightly soluble in CS2, HCl, petroleum

**Nonivamide** is soluble in methanol

...

So, obviously these are all non-edibles, except for alcohol. But I don't really like the idea of consuming alcohol to every meal. It just doesn't sound very healthy. Does anyone have an idea of how to create a hot but tasteless "sauce" or powder from pure capsaicin / nonivamide?

Comment: Since the only edible solvent in your list is alcohol, do you really have a choice?  Perhaps dissolve in alcohol then add an oil and cook off the alcohol?

Comment: I think capsaicin is not very heat resistant. Also, how can it not be soluble in oil, but if you solve it in alcohol and cook it in oil it can? I think I don't really understand the concept of solubility.

Comment: Cooking off alcohol is almost never 100%, so what you would be doing is dissolving it in alcohol and then removing all but trace amounts of the alcohol in quantities too small to be a health concern or to be considered an alcoholic food/beverage by legal authorities.  That said, I have no idea how it would actually behave, but that's the direction I would head with my experiment.

Comment: Or why not add the least possible amount of alcohol which is required to completely dissolve it and add the right amount of oil to it in order to acquire the correct SHU? Will alcohol mix with oil, and do I need 100 vol% alcohol or will Vodka do just fine?

Comment: You're just looking for a carrier, so I would think almost any liquid will do.  I was just thinking that oil would be a more convenient and traditional way to serve it.  I suppose you could even just skip the oil and use Vodka, but the less alcohol and more water you use, the longer it will take to cook off.  I'd use a liquor with the highest alcohol content possible (probably Everclear in the US).

Comment: So just oil and no alcohol would also do?

Comment: I don't think so.  You've got to start with a solvent.  I meant any liquid would do once you've got it dissolved.

Comment: So I will dissolve it in ethanol and simply add oil to it. As long as oil and ehtanol mix, it will work, I think.

Comment: I believe capsaicin is fat soluble; you might try an oil base.

Comment: Look up Capsacin emulsion. There's very likely an oil or surfactant mix that'll work for you already described. You just need to wade through the possibilities: https://www.google.com/search?q=Capsaicin+emulsion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Just my two cents: This doesn't seem very healthy.

Comment: There are three reasons to care less about consuming miniscule amounts of ethyl alcohol.  1) There is some alcohol in most (or all?) fermented foods and drinks, including all fermented milk products except yoghurt (?), 2) wine is a popular component in European cuisine and a few tbsps are often added during cooking, 3) ethanol boils at 78°C, and if your process requires any amount of heating water to boiling point, most of alcohol will evaporate.

Comment: On top of that, it's not like you will need 100 grams of ethanol to dissolve a meal's worth of capsaicin.  Most likely you will need at most a few mgs of solvent per serving, as it solves easily.

Comment: @MischaArefiev, depends on what you mean by "most of the alcohol", but [it actually takes a long time to reduce the alcohol concentration](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/659/cooking-away-alcohol/672#672) to even 10%.

Comment: @Marti thanks for the info.  The numbers seem to be a bit high, but stil if you evaporate 60% technically you evaporate *most* of the alcohol :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If capsaicin is soluble in alcohol, and you want a sauce with heat but no taste, there's a very simple way to do it if you do get a hold of pure capsaicin. Keep in mind that pepper sprays used for personal protection or law enforcement are in the range of 10% to 30% capsaicin. Bear spray (commonly seen here in Alaska) is required by law to be at or under 2% capsaicin. If you consider *that* then you've got to realize that you don't want a capsaicin concentration of greater than 1% anywhere near your food, and if you create a 1% solution, that's a product that you would only want to use by the micro-drop.

So, if you're using your capsaicin solution by the *micro-drop*, how great of a health concern can it possibly be that the carrier of your capsaicin is vodka? There's more naturally occurring alcohol in  a glass of fruit juice than in a micro-drop of vodka.

So, just get yourself a little airline bottle of vodka, that will be 30mls of vodka. For this purpose, lets pretend that vodka weighs 1 gram per ml. That's not exactly right, vodka weighs slightly less, but calling 30mls of vodka 30 grams is fine for this. So, to achieve a 1% capsaicin solution in the vodka, you would add 0.3 grams of pure capsaicin to to the bottle. Shake and you're done.

If you do get a hold of pure capsaicin, please treat it with great care and use protective clothing. Obviously if a 2% solution works as a bear repellant, the pure stuff could really hurt you.

EDIT: Also, see my comment to GdD below.

Comment: I thought it might be a bit provoking if I put drops of Vodka on my food at the work place, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Silly, just transfer to a different container! :)

Comment: Yes, I was going to use an eye-dropper or something :D Otherwise someone would drink out of that bottle and would get an unexpected surprise.

Comment: That would be unpleasant. :)

Comment: Even with an eyedropper you would still be getting too much at that concentration. You'd need lab equipment to measure that stuff out precisely.

Comment: @GdD Honestly, I think 1% would be too high too, but that could be further diluted in just about anything. To measure out .3 grams (or even as little as .03 grams for a .1% solution) all he'd need is a [gram scale](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0012LOQUQ/ref=ox_sc_act_title_4?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER), easily purchased for $11. I haven't looked, but I think being able to buy pure capsaicin is pretty unlikely, I think he'll be dealing with a dilution to start with. The dilution level should be pretty clear on the item, so he'd be able to do what I suggested easily.

Comment: Why not do the vodka and then dilute that into water as appropriate?

Comment: @sourd'oh I see no reason why not.

Comment: A former roommate had a container of 'pure cap'.  [It was a smaller dropper bottle inside a child proof container.](http://www.amazon.com/Pure-Cap-Hot-Sauce-Ferociously/dp/B0000DG4NJ)

Comment: @Jolenealaska : if you like sriracha, look for [sambal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sambal) ... it tends to be much more concetrated.  There are different varieties, but the one in the US is generally sambal oelek, which can be used to make many other types.  (most of the stuff in the US is from Huy Fong, the same company that popularized sriracha.

Comment: I buy that in the jumbo size too :)

Answer (score 12):

There's no point in getting pure capsaicin and diluting it yourself when you can buy capsaicin in just about any strength you want with all the work done for you. If you want something truly, painfully hot then get capsaicin 1 mil and then measure it into your dishes with an eye dropper. Be real careful with it, use gloves and don't sniff it, even at 1M it can still seriously hurt you.

I second @Jolenealaska's warning that pure capsaicin is dangerous. In fact, you should not try to get the pure stuff even if it is available, get something somewhat diluted as it is safer and easier to work with. Pure capsaicin is used in industrial applications, you need to work in tiny quantities, requiring special equipment. It can also put you in the hospital, so just don't do it. As cool as it sounds "I made this sauce using pure capsaicin!", the reality is somewhat different.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 2):

There's a product on the market called 'Pure Cap', which is exactly what you're proposing to make:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Pure-Cap-Hot-Sauce-Ferociously/dp/B0000DG4NJ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000DG4NJ)

It comes in a dropper bottle inside a child-proof container.  One my former housemates (before he was living with me) had a container ... it seemed more useful for a (not very funny) practical joke than for actual food.

Maybe you could use it to make your own hot sauce, but I didn't really find it useful as an ingredient on its own.  (of course, I've also grown thai bird chilies, and get scotch bonnets & habaneros from my stepfather, so I already had a source of good heat).

Comment: If it weren't $30, I'd buy that. I go through sriracha like water.

Answer (score 0):

While sauces with 200'000+ scoville units do have hot peppers in them, many of them (Blair's Mega Death sauce included) use capsaicin extract to achieve that heat. When taste testing I have always found that those sauces which utilize capsaicin extract tend to have an unpleasant metallic taste.

If you would like to make a good tasting super hot sauce I would recommend to use hotter peppers such as the Carolina Reaper, Trinidad Moruga Scorpion or Naga Viper instead of capsaicin extract.

There are also existing hot sauces which use this method such as the Hot Ones | the last Dab XXX or the Heatonist #1 and others. I personally find the taste of these nice and I am not left wanting for more heat.

Answer (score -1):

The only reason I can think of to buy pure capsaicin is to create a hotter hot sauce than what is available [https://www.amazon.com/Mad-Dog-357-Plutonium-Scoville/dp/B00IIUEOEW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IIUEOEW)
Assuming that you have read how hot pure cap is 16 million and before you buy this most sites require you to acknowledge this. I reconfused why people are trying to tell people that pure capsaicin is hotter than what he wants without knowing how hot he actually wants it.

Now to answer the question capsaicin will dissolve in oils, fats, and alcohols. Pure capsaicin equals 16 million if you are trying to make something less than that use a dropper.

Answer (score -1):

I use capsaicin all the time. I grow killer habañero chilis, and collect the fruits and dry them and the seeds. Once dry (it can take a hot week), I separate the seeds from the fruit.

Then I put the seeds in water and simmer them several times over a day or two. This is because water does dissolve a bit of just about everything, including chili oils.

Comment: Capsaicin in chile peppers is mostly found in the ribs, much moreso than the flesh or seeds. In any case, your approach does not produce the concentrated capsaicin solution the OP was looking for. The concentration will be limited by the amount of capsaicin in the seeds (though that could of course be mitigated by using a lot of seeds and not much water),  and more importantly the limited solubility of capsaicin in water.