# Alcohol evaporation of beer in a cake

Tags: baking, cake, alcohol, beer

I'd like to bake a Guinness flavored cocoa cake. My direction say to start by beating room temperature butter with brown sugar, then eggs and a mixture of flour, cocoa powder and baking powder. Finally, incorporate the Guinness as it is. The picture show also the foam.

My question is: I'd like to heat the beer beforehand in order to have the alcohol evaporate; bring it back to room temperature and then incorporate it.

Do you think it will affect a good raising/cooking and the texture of the cake?

Comment: Baking the cake itself will help evaporate some of the alcohol. (also see other answer)

Comment: Also note that any sourdough bread has some alcohol, as do overripe bananas and various other foods.

Comment: You are going to lose like two parts alcohol to one part water to even boil it down from 4.3% to 2%.

Answer (score 4):

Alcohol never all evaporates unless you evaporate all the water as well. The actual amount per slice is minimal anyway - equivalent to about a shot of beer in a portion, in the recipe I use. If even that's too much for you, start with de-alcoholised beer. You may have trouble finding alcohol-free stout.

From the [USDA Table of Nutrient Retention Factors Release 6](http://www.ars.usda.gov/SP2UserFiles/Place/12354500/Data/retn/retn06.pdf) quoted in [merl's answer to a related question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/13689/20413), baking reduces the alcohol to 25% in an hour and 10% in 2 hours. Quite a lot of water will evaporate as well during that time.

Comment: Also see the answers to [Cooking Away Alcohol](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/659/cooking-away-alcohol) for more references.  Basically, baking for two and an half hours should do the job!

Comment: Thanks @wumpus - finding old questions on the mobile site isn't quick. I'll copy over some of the citations.

Comment: @wumpusD'00m the problem is that doing that reduces the volume so it's necessary to add water or else the batter will be too dry.

Comment: @Catija Oh yes.  The "**baking** for two and an half hours" was intended as a joke.  I think the result would be akin to a charred oatcake :)